# Did the US Federal government take 3 months from the warning its BARDA chief to require more production of N95 masks?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, public-health

This exchange from a Congressional hearing was mentioned on Twitter and cited by [some news](https://nowthisnews.com/politics/were-in-deep-shit-ousted-vaccine-director-testifies-before-congress-about-trumps)

> Q: "It took 3 months from your initial warnings...for the federal government to...require the production of millions more n95 masks...What was the consequence of this 3-month delay? Were lives endangered?"
>
> DR. BRIGHT: "Lives were endangered, and I believe lives were lost."

Note that Dr. Bright didn't confirm the exact time frame in that answer, but did not dispute it either. So, is it true that it took 3 months from the time that Dr. Bright warned about the insufficient production (or stockpiles?) until the Federal government took official action to have production increased?